# node js cassandra driver ResponseError: line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'

Tags: node.js, cassandra-2.1

Not able to connect to cassandra database using cassandra-driver.

Cassandra version is 2.1.5, cassandra-driver version is 2.1.

`var cassandra = require("cassandra-driver");`

`var cassandraClient = new cassandra.Client({
    contactPoints: [
        hostAddress
    ],
    keyspace: [name]
});`

`cassandraClient.connect(function (err, result) {`

```
    if(err) {
       console.log('Can not connect to Cassandra host - ', config.cassandra.host);
       console.log('Error connecting cassandra is - ', err);
    } else {
       console.log('Successfully connected to cassandra.');
    }
```

});

`cassandraClient.on('log', function(level, className, message, furtherInfo) {
      console.log('log event: %s -- %s', level, message);
});`

Comment: Same code running on local totally fine, getting error only on aws.

Comment: Security groups is OK?

Comment: Issue was  value of keyspace was undefined

Answer (score 0):

On debugging found that name of keyspace was `undefined`.